# xml data over network tcp . please help

Tags: c#, xml, network-programming, packets

I have devices. Each one sends data to (server IP-address) over a particular port in a random time. Because it's an alarm device and it’s possible that more than one device fired in the same time.
The data is in XML Format.

Now I already got a small windows application which listen for the data But I got a few problems

1. problem is that the application is sniffing the packets. Mean that I can get the data in the TCP packets ....that’s mean that I will get the XML divided in the packets And not in sequence (order by time)...that’s make it so hard to read the XML data Or just arrange it and read from it. I need to read that data coming from the device and save it in XML format. even if I'm listening to one device , packets not coming in order

Any idea how to do that. I saw some other Questions here and I tried all this answers but nothing talking about reading the XML file. I’m using the same code as in this article

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/CSNetworkSniffer.aspx

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use low-level tcp sockets? It seems like using a WCF service would be easier as long as it meets your requirements.

Comment: If you're using TCP, then the data for each connection should be arriving in order. Make sure you are using a separate connection for each device, and storing the data for each device separately.

Comment: nothing working from the above..i tried alot of methods to get it working but nothing working .
data not coming in order at all

Comment: Why are you using a sniffer to receive XML data? Why not just listen on a TCP port yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sniffing the RAW packets that are passing through the network driver. At this low level it will be up to you to process and reconstruct the messages by analysing the packets and using things like the TCP seq, the ack/nak messages etc.

Here is the wikipedia article on the TCP protocol that might help you get started before delving into the deeper side of things.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol

And of course the most critical source the RFC.
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793

i assume you are sniffing the data because you have some other application that is actually acting as a server and listening for the data. If now you really should just write an application that listens on the TCP port and reads the data from there. This way the TCP protocol will ensure that you receive all the data in the right order etc. To get started with this, you could use the [TcpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx) class, or you go use the lower level [Socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx) classes